# Physical explanation of Dirac-Born-Infeld (DBI) inflation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, cosmological-inflation

[image]

I am studying the Dirac-Born-Infeld (DBI) inflation model and came across this question in a past exam paper from Cambridge that considered the following Lagrangian:

$$\mathcal{L}=\sqrt{-g}A(X,\phi)$$ where $$X=\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi$$ and $A$ is given by:

$$A=\frac{1}{f(\phi)}\Big(1-\sqrt{1-2Xf(\phi)}\Big)-V(\phi)$$

where $f(\phi)$ is the warp factor of the throat.

I calculated the slow roll parameter which is given by:

$$\epsilon=3\frac{\frac{\gamma}{2}\dot{\phi}^2}{\frac{\gamma^2}{\gamma+1}\dot{\phi}^2+V}$$ where $$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2Xf(\phi)}}$$

The problem then asks to provide a physical explanation on why inflation can be achieved even if $\epsilon_V>1$ which is different from the more conventional models seen. I can see from the $\epsilon$ that the kinetic energy times $\gamma$ must be smaller than $V$ but can't see any physical explanation for why inflation can work for $\epsilon_V>1$.

Comment: Please cite the paper's link.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Sorry, by paper I meant a past exam paper from Cambridge. I have attached a screenshot of the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DBI inflation, the inflaton is the scalar field parameterizing the position of a brane evolving in a warped throat geometry.  Being a physical object, the brane is constrained to move at subluminal velocities, regardless of the steepness of the potential -- hence the Lorentz contraction in the kinetic term.  This factor has the effect of a speed limit, allowing the field to evolve relatively slowly even in steep potentials.